# Type 'UILayoutPriority' has no member 'defaultHigh'

Tags: xcode9.2, swift3.2

When using this code in our app, we run into an error:

```
let value = UILayoutPriority.defaultHigh // Error: Type 'UILayoutPriority' has no member 'defaultHigh'.
```

which is super wired because according to the documentation, it is obviously there. And also, if we click through `UILayoutPriority` and jump to its definition, we see it there as well.

**UIKit** > **NSLayoutConstraint**:

```
extension UILayoutPriority {

    @available(iOS 6.0, *)
    public static let required: UILayoutPriority
```

So why we cannot use `UILayoutPriority.defaultHigh`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It turns out that we need to use `UILayoutPriorityDefaultHigh` since our code base is still using Swift 3.2. The source code for iOS UIKit is in Swift 4, that's why it is super confusing for us. In Swift 4 and after, we'll use `UILayoutPriority.defaultHigh`.

Need to spend the time and do the migration soon!